# How to close an applcation with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Thanks to open or opn in node js I'm able to open an Excel file. But after this, I want to close this one.

Do you know something to close an application with node js ?

Thank you,
Mathieu

Answer (score 0):

You can use kill or fkill to send a signal to the application:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/kill
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/fkill

But you'd need to know its PID. See other modules:

- https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/kill